# Swift push controller back onto nav stack

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have seen many examples of how to push a VC onto another nav stack but not on how to push a VC from outside of the nav stack, back into the main nav stack.

I have a navigation stack and on one of my views, I have a button that presents a popover that is not part of the nav stack. When user taps on a button in this popover, I want to present a VC thats part of the original navigation stack.

All I have is this so far; which creates a new navigation and presets the VC on it:

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "report") as! ConditionReportViewController
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

    self.present(nav, animated: true)
```

Comment: You might need to give us an example.

Comment: agreed with @RakeshaShastri

Comment: What do you mean by "back into the main nav stack"?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you please try to explain again what do you want to achieve?